# Как реализовать порядковый номер записей в бд?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Сабж.
К примеру есть такая модель

```C#
public class SettingRedirect
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Identifier { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

В бд несколько записей, в `Identifier` хранится их порядковый номер. Порядковый номер записей будет иногда меняться. К примеру мы извлекаем объект с номером 10, и перемещаем его вверх по списку выставляя номер 5. Но запись с номером 5 уже существует, получается надо сделать так 10=>5=>6=>7=>8=>9=>10.
Можно делать запрос к бд и выбирать сразу все записи, и если произошло изменение то делаем +1 в `Identifier` ко всем записям которые ниже по порядку. 
В общем вопрос в том есть ли какой то встроенный механизм для реализации порядкового номера или может быть есть простое решение?
Пока я только придумал метод который просто будет тупо делать +1.

Comment: https://schoolsw3.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.php

Comment: Как много будет записей в таблице? И как часто порядковый номер может меняться? Если записей планируется относительно немного и номер будет меняться не часто, то, как вариант, можно предложить следующее: изначально делаем номера наподобие 100, 200, 300 и т. д. При изменении номера с 1000 на 500, если 500 уже есть, даём номер 550. Или 525 или 575. То есть делим интервал пополам. При этом другие записи передвигать не нужно. Лишь когда интервал исчерпается, придётся записи двигать. Естественно, интервал можно увеличить.

Comment: Записей не много, 20 думаю максимум, и меняться буду не совсем часто но буду добавляться новые

Comment: [Хранение порядка строк в таблице](https://www.sql.ru/forum/1180988/hranenie-poryadka-strok-v-tablice) - обсуждение аналогичного вопроса

Comment: *Записей не много, 20 думаю максимум* Тогда не надо хранить порядок как номер, храните его как next_id. Для извлечения и динамической нумерации используйте рекурсивный CTE.

Comment: По поводу CTE. У вас стоит метка Entity Framework. Он не умеет CTE. Зато это [умеет](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html) linq2db. Как вариант, можно взять библиотеку [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) - она добавит в EF возможность использовать CTE и много других вкусностей.

Comment: Ну а что, кстати, и нормально делать `+1` всем записям больше определённого номера. Операция простая, понятная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За чем так сложно?

Вариант без autoincrement:

1. Считываем все записи из таблицы в List или другую collection.
2. Производим манипуляции над данными: Сортируем, заново присваемваем ID
3. Если все удачно - опустошаем таблицу
4. Записаем наш заново отсортированный список в таблицу с помощью INSERT

Comment: При работе с БД, самые дорогие операции - это передача данных туда и обратно. Вы предлагаете гонять данные туда-сюда. Вас спасёт только то, что у автора данных мало. 
 А можно перенумерацию сделать прямо в БД.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Если бы автор вверху не написал, что у него небольшой набор данных - я бы не стал предлагать этот вариант ;)

Comment: Я согласен, что это вполне рабочее решение. Поэтому не минусую, не голосую за закрытие. Просто комментирую, что сделать эту операцию прямо в БД было бы лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь, я правильно поняла задачу.

Условимся, что индекс объекта будет иметь название Index (при желании можно изменить).

Тогда можно создать следующий интерфейс:

```
public interface IIndex
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Интерфейс IIndex будет требовать наличие поля Index в классах, в которых это будет необходимо (В примере для класса ExampleClass).

Реализуем интерфейс в классе ExampleClass:

```
public class ExampleClass : IIndex
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Тип данных List предоставляет методы для удобной манипуляции списками (Add, Insert, Remove и прочие). Эти методы могут изменять порядок индексов (как в массивах).

По сути, класс List уже сделал всю "грязную" работу с индексами за нас. Нам лишь нужен метод, который запишет фактическое значение индекса по списку в свойство Index у класса, который реализует интерфейс IIndex. Средствами C# узнать, реализует ли объект интерфейс или нет можно с помощью ключевого слова where.

К классу List было бы хорошо добавить свой метод, манипулирующий свойством Index. Создадим же свой тип данных ListIndex:

```
public class ListIndex<T> : List<T> where T : IIndex
{
    public void SortIndex() //Обновляет свойство Index, начиная с 1
    {
        for (int i=0;i<this.Count; i++)
        {
            this[i].Index = i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

В этом классе мы унаследовали весь функционал от List, но указали, что объекты, которые могут там находиться, должны реализовывать IIndex.

Метод SortIndex позволяет обновить все индексы к фактическому значению, но начиная с 1-цы (при желании можно изменить).

Теперь всё готово для того, чтобы использовать эту схему на практике.

Файловая структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример работы в Program.cs :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Условимся, что по правилам системы некий список индексируется с единицы.
        //Если выборка происходит из БД, то заполняем List по порядку через цикл For

        //Заполнение списка
        ListIndex<ExampleClass> ListObject = new ListIndex<ExampleClass>()
        {
            new ExampleClass {Id=1, Index = 1, Name = "Первый"},
            new ExampleClass {Id=2, Index = 2, Name = "Второй"},
            new ExampleClass {Id=35, Index = 3, Name = "Зелёный"},
            new ExampleClass {Id=7, Index = 4, Name = "Ананас"},
            new ExampleClass {Id=3, Index = 5, Name = "Утюг"}
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Вывод до манипуляции ->");
        for (int i = 0; i < ListObject.Count; i++)
        {
            ExampleClass obj = ListObject[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"{obj.Id}, {obj.Index}, {obj.Name}");
        }

        ExampleClass cloneObject = ListObject.Find(x => x.Id == 35);//Берём объект из списка
        ExampleClass newObject = new ExampleClass() //Клонируем объект
        {
            Id = cloneObject.Id,
            Name = cloneObject.Name,

        };

        newObject.Name = "Вставка"; //Изменяем имя объекта
        ListObject.Insert(2, newObject);//Вставляем на третью позицию в список объект

        ListObject.Add(new ExampleClass() { Id = 87, Name = "Василий" }); //Добавляем новый объект

        Console.WriteLine("\nВывод после манипуляции ->");
        for (int i = 0; i < ListObject.Count; i++)
        {
            ExampleClass obj = ListObject[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"{obj.Id}, {obj.Index}, {obj.Name}");
        }

        ListObject.SortIndex();//Перезаписываем индексы

        Console.WriteLine("\nВывод после \"сортировки\" ->");
        for (int i = 0; i < ListObject.Count; i++)
        {
            ExampleClass obj = ListObject[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"{obj.Id}, {obj.Index}, {obj.Name}");
        }

    }
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.:

- Если задача единичная, то это можно было бы реализовать в связанной с обновлением индексов функции.
- В случае необходимости поменять местами объекты в списке, можно добавить соответствующую функцию в класс ListIndex.
- Если индексы нужно выводить куда-то динамически, то к ним можно обратиться по факту.
- Если индексы нужно привязывать к WPF-интерфейсу, можно добавить ещё одну функцию (или переопределить Insert), которая изменяет индексы, начиная с вставленной в список записи и до конца (прибавляя 1-цу).
- Если всю эту работу нужно проделывать в T-SQL, то у него есть функция ROW_NUMBER() (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Суть вопроса автора: как менять нумерацию в БД. Всё, что вы написали - мимо. PS: row_number() в данном случае не помощник: она назначит строкам _свои_ номера, а нужно сохранить и передвинуть имеющиеся.

Comment: Тогда зачем в тегах C# и .net? В случае если нужно работать только с БД, нужно делать какие-нибудь триггеры и функции на стороне бд. В любом случае, при модификации списка нужно перезаписывать порядковый номер, а это можно сделать очень разными способами. Я предложила свой.

Comment: Я не возражаю против вашего предложения. Просто считаю, что лучше было бы это делать в БД, PS: у автора упомянут Entity Framework, значит можно использовать ORM - исходя из этого, я бы взял linq2db и не написав ни строчки SQL, а только C#, сделал бы с помощью CTE. Но это уже за рамками вопроса.

Comment: Так индексы - это обычное перезаписываемое поле. Ничего не мешает результирующий список записать с помощью EF.

Comment: В EF будет два запроса: select и update. А можно обойтись всего одним запросом.

Comment: Ещё речь идёт и о вставке новой записи. Нужно использовать Entry.State у каждого объекта.